# Drawing VectorDrawable on SurfaceView Canvas [EDITED]

Tags: android

I have a vector image I wanna draw on a SurfaceView.

I exported it as .SVG , then I used the android studio "new > Vector Asset"  to generate the .XML file in my "app/res/drawable"

Now, How do I draw it on the canvas ?

Note: I don't want to use any other .xml file, I just have my method that has the canvas ready to draw on, so how do I get the VectorDrawable from the .xml ressource file, to be able to do `myVector.draw(canvas);`  ?

**EDIT 1**
I tried (for hours) the solution provided in pskink's comment, still no luck:

I have the `Android Support Library` (installed from the SDK manager in Android Studio)

and I added the dependency of `v7-appCompat` to the Gradle file,

the problem is that I still can't import the VectorDrawableCompat
(though the file .java exists in the `sdk/source/android-23/android/graphics/drawable/` and not in the `sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/` )

Could someone help me import VectorDrawabaleCompat ?

Comment: `Resources#getDrawable`

Comment: `getDrawable()` requires min API 21, is there any solution for retrieving the drawable in older APIs ? like API 8 ?

Comment: use a method with the only int parameter

Comment: getDrawable(int) is deprecated

Comment: the docs say `This method was deprecated in API level 22.` are you using API level 22 ?

Comment: also `VectorDrawable` was added in API level 21 so there is no way you would use it in API level 8 (unless you use a `VectorDrawableCompat` from support library)

Comment: What would be the best approach to solve this ? What can I do to use Vectors but still keep the min API at 8 ? (or should I just give up on Vectors and draw "simple shapes with paths" ? or should I just use .PNG files ?

Comment: use the latest support library,  `VectorDrawableCompat` is inside `support-vector-drawable` package, more: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: From the readme in the git repo `vector-compat - A support library for VectorDrawable and AnimatedVectorDrawable introduced in Lollipop with fully backwards compatible tint support (api 14+ so far)` (So API 8 is not supported I think)

Comment: see the link i posted above: `Adds support for VectorDrawable assets to apps running on API level 7 or higher. AnimatedVectorDrawable assets are also supported on API level 11 or higher. `

Comment: (I don't understand why I can "draw" (let's say a triangle with rounded corners) using path.cubicTo() , but I can't use the same path information in the .xml to draw the path automatically :/ Could someone clarify please ?)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I didn't see the link

Comment: i gave it in my prev comment ("use the latest support library,")

Comment: Could you please check the edit, I'm still struggling even after reading the documentation 10 times,,

Comment: it is inside `support-vector-drawable`, not in `v7-appCompat`

Comment: in the `support-vector-drawable` I find .aar .md5 .sha1 .pom and the `support-vector-drawable-23.2.0-sources.jar` (I guess the latter is the one I should use, but how ? how can I import/use it ?)

Comment: everything is in .aar, just add it to gradle like you did with appCompat-v7

Comment: Finally ! Thank You sooooo much, would you want to answer the question so I would mark your answer as solution? ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to support older platforms you should use `support-vector-drawable` support library, add something like this to build.gradle as a dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0'
```

and use `VectorDrawableCompat.create()` to get your `Drawable`